# Wcf ria: using sql function while inserting row

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I need to know if i can use `getdate()` when I insert row in a table using `wcf ria service`. I'm developing a Silverlight application using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use DateTime.Now?

Comment: You're right, but assuming both are in the same time zone and using the same source to set their time--it should be okay (or at least only off by a few seconds). Hopefully, anyway :)

Comment: How about a database trigger to update the date on row creation?

Comment: maybe it's the only solution! or a web service that returns the server time

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use T-SQL GetDate() as the default value for a column in your database, this will set it automatically when you create new rows.

```
ALTER TABLE x
ADD DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR x.yourcolumn
GO
```

Comment: its doesnt work! when a row is inserted yhe datetime column value is null!!

Comment: if you need the column to be nullable, maybe ignore what I just said and set the date time in your Insert method of your RIA service. If you want it to never be null, if you change the column to not allow nulls then it will insert the default, which will GetDate()

Comment: i tried it anr removed the allow null property on the field but no luck! an exception ocured!